# Plurals in Twig Symfony 5

Tags: symfony, twig, translation

As of Twig 3.x the filter `transchoice` is deprecated, I'm trying to figure out how is the proper syntax for twig, as [docs are centered](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/message_format.html#pluralization) in php syntax.

This is my `messages.en.yml` file:

```
client: >-
            {number, plural,
                one {Client}
                other {Clients}
            }
```

And this is my twig template, trying to figure out what it should be according to [this doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/templates.html#using-twig-filters):

```
{{"client"|trans({'number': 2})}}
```

The result is this string, this is, the variable `number` is not being processed:

> {2, plural, one {Client} other {Clients} }

So, what is the correct syntax to see only `Client` or `Clients` depending on number?

Comment: Can you share more details? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Structuring your translation that way is using the ICU Message Format. In order to use the ICU Message Format, the message domain file has to be suffixed with `+intl-icu`.

Make sure you [name your file correctly](https://symfony.com/doc/current/translation/message_format.html#using-the-icu-message-format):

```
translations/messages+intl-icu.en.yaml
```

Comment: That was it. As a side effect I had to install library `symfony/polyfill-intl-messageformatter` or PHP `intl` package. I installed the first one and it works ok.